# How exactly does buying directly from Westvleteren work?

Tags: breweries

Even if I managed to reserve some beer, it appears [here](http://www.sintsixtus.be/eng/brouwerij.htm) that I need my own car, or at least one whose plate # I will know long in advance to pick up beer.  Has anyone done this?  What is the exact procedure?

Comment: Later today ill answer your question. Been there done that ;).

Comment: Thanks, all good answers. I know I am supposed to accept but it doesn't seem remember me . Phil, do you suppose you can always use your ID rather than license plate ( the issue is, can I do it in a rented car ) or is it because you were a repeat customer ?

Answer (score 11):

I live in Amsterdam, and I have not personally been to Westvleteren but I have friends who have made the trip. It turns out that you have a few options:

1. You can call and make an appointment and IF you get an
   appointment then you must drive there at the appointed time to pick
   up your crate of bier. If you can't make it at the appointed time
   then you lose out, and you must start the process all over again. I
   forget how much bier this is for, but I think it is 24-48 bottles. Indeed when you make the appointment then you must supply your license place number which they use to keep track of you. They will not allow you to make 2 appointments with the same license plate number in a 60 day period. Additionally, the phone number you must call to get an appointment is always busy, I have heard of people using automatic redial for hours before they finally get through.
2. If you are in the area (again you will need a car, because there is no public transport, and biking there is unreasonable from most places.) You can pop in and there is a small shop next to the monastery where you can buy a 6 pack per person without appointment, and also with out a huge price markup. Of course while you are there you can also eat some good food, and buy other items that the monks make and sell. This is much less hassle, but you cannot get much bier, so it may not be worth trekking all the way out there specifically for this.  However if you are in the area already and you have the time to take a small detour then you should certainly pop in for lunch or dinner and get some tasty brew.
3. Finally if you are in the Benelux region you can sometimes find Westvleteren in local shops or cafes, however the prices range from 10-16 euros per bottle (in Amsterdam) which is a lot more than you will pay at the monastery. (However, beer bought at the monastery isn't meant for selling, it's meant for private consumption, it says so every time you buy some)

Comment: I have done this twice and I would like to add my thoughts: The most difficult part is the phone part to make the appointment. I tried it twice. The first time I called for a whole day (about 150 calls) before I finally have them. The seconde time my girlfriend and I called for a day and a half (about 250 calls) to have an answer. I suggest that you prepare yourself for that :)

Comment: Also, you can't chose which beer you will have, it depends on the week as Valentin Grégoire said : http://www.sintsixtus.be/bierverkoopactueel.htm You should try to have the 8 or the 12, the blond is more "classic" When you are there, try the In De Vrede Inn near the monastery, you may be able to buy some more. And I advise you to try their Westvleteren Paté wich is quite awesome :)

Comment: You have to wonder how much of the process is intentional in order to inflate their mystique, and consequently their demand. I've had a handful of Westvlet 12's, and it's barely distinguishable from Rochefort 10 which I can get my hands on pretty easily on the regular.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to what Chris has answered, here are some nice to knows:

To see which beer is available at which time etc, look at this page: 
http://www.sintsixtus.be/bierverkoopactueel.htm

In addition to the 60 days you need to wait for your license plate, also your phone number will be blocked once you made an order for the beer.
Callers with an anonymous phone number will be blocked automatically.

One crate of 24 bottles costs:

- Trappist Westvleteren Blond      (5,8 vol.% alc.)    30,00 euro
- Trappist Westvleteren Acht (dark)    (8 vol.% alc.)      35,00 euro
- Trappist Westvleteren Twaalf (dark)  (10,2 vol.% alc.)   40,00 euro

The Trappist Westvleteren Twaalf is the dark beer that won several prizes and is world famous.
In my opinion, the Blond and the Acht are a bit overrated (opinion!!).

You could in fact go by buss, but that would be really complicated and almost impossible to do, so indeed it's better to go by car/taxi.

In the end, if you think it's not worth it, you could try the St. Bernardus Abt 12 beer. It's is brewed almost the exact same way and it tastes pretty much the same.
The Sint Bernardus Abt 12 is basically for sale throughout whole Belgium in every big grocery store (or beer/drink shop).

In addition to the abbey, you can also buy the beer in the café/restaurant nearby. However, depending which beer is left over, that beer will be for sale and you can only buy 1 pack of 6 bottles per person (if there would be any left!).
You could also just go there and sit and enjoy a Westvleteren there because they sell them there :).
You could also buy glasses and some other souvenirs at the café. They have a little shop.

If you have any questions in addition, please don't hesitate!

Comment: I wouldn't say Rochefort is similar to Westvleteren. In my opinion it tastes completely different. Good beer though!

Answer (score 2):

Just returned  from the abbey after collecting some westy 12
Being as I was going in friends car the monk takes your name and used that instead of car reg is on his paperwork 
The monk also asked me if my car reg was still the same! Must put car reg numbers to phone numbers from the last time we managed to get a booking . Clever monks
While there we collected another 12 bottles each from the inn they had all 3 for sale
And yes it is worth seeking out
We drove over 700mile round trip from UK to collect

Comment: Nice road trip! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to note is try and use a car if you are going for the simple six pack.  If you don't you can rent bikes from Hotel Palace? I believe in the center market. The hotel isn't open on Sundays.